# How to display list of videos one after another?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to display list of videos which *URLS* coming form Ajax result one after another in one view sequentially.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetAllvideos",
            data: '',
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, r) {
                $("#myVideo").append("<source src='" + r.Url + "' type='video/mp4'>");
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>




<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="400" controls>

</video>
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: What is the response to this ajax request?

Comment: this ajax callback GetAllvideos() function which return JSON result of Videos object

`// GET: videos
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAllvideos()
        {
            var data = db.Videos;
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what that actually looks like when sent to a browser.  Check your developer tools network tab to see what form the data appears to the browser.

Comment: `[{"Id":1,
"Name":"001 Lets start this amazing journey.mp4","Url":"E:\\Tutorials\\projects\\IMCchannel\\IMCchannel\\Uploaded\\0712af8e-d02e-4844-836d-0a3c9579f8fd001 Lets start this amazing journey.mp4"}]`

Comment: Should `#div1` be `#myVideo`?

Comment: i already edit it .

Comment: You could override the `GetAllvideos()` action to it returns HTML markup of the list items. So it will be possible to update the list container by the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:
You can register an "onended" event on the video tag and reload the video. something like this:

```
$("#myVideo") = function(){
    currentUrlIndex++;
    $("#myVideo").children[0].src = urlList[currentUrlIndex];
    $("#myVideo").load();
    $("#myVideo").play();
}
```

Comment: the local url works when i use one url, the idea, to save all comming urls from the response ajax and loop on it, during looping play video after finish the current url call the next and play it... and so one

Comment: Oh, in this case you can register an "onended" event on the video tag and reload the video. something like this:

#myVideo.onended = function(){
    currentUrlIndex++;
    #myVideo.children[0].src = urlList[currentUrlIndex];
    #myVideo.load();
    #myVideo.play();
}

Comment: this a new type of Error < to solve this... i think about splice the current index array to load only
`/Uploaded/002%20Dont%20be%20a%20good%20student,%20be%20an%20amazing%20student.mp4`